# Assocative array to php table

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have json encoded string which I'm converting to php/html table but its not working.

All data should come in text files error in `foreach : invalid argument`

html should be:

```
id    text             date

1     NY John 9999999  yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm
```

Code:

```
<h2 class="title-list">Vle Data List</h2>
<div class="vlist" style="margin:10px auto; width:95%;">
  <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" id='list'  width="100%">
    <tr class="tblhead">
      <th>S.No.</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $pagenum = isset( $_GET['pagenum'] ) ? absint( $_GET['pagenum'] ) : 1;
    $limit = 100; // number of rows in page
    $offset = ( $pagenum - 1 ) * $limit;
    $total = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM wp_data" );
    $num_of_pages = ceil( $total / $limit );
    $entries = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_data LIMIT $offset, $limit");
    foreach($entries as $print) {?>

    <td><?php $print->id; ?></td>
    <td>
    <?php
    $json= $print->text;
    json_decode($json);
    $vledata =json_decode($json, true);


    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($vledata as $key => $value) 
    {
     echo "<tr>". $key ."</tr>";
     echo "<tr>". $value . "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>"; ?></td>
      <td><?php $print->data; ?></td>
      <?php } ?>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to build a table within a table?

Comment: yes but just show value not key of array

Comment: What line gives you Invalid argument ? You're not giving an array to one of your foreach loops

Comment: seconf foeach loop Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: @MaheshDigarse You really don't want to be putting SQL in your front end work, good applications are almost always built in layers(MVC for example has Models for the data, Views for the display layer and Controllers for the logic). If you do this now and ever want to change your database structure you're going to cause yourself problems.

Comment: Right before your second foreach loop, can you add `var_dump($vledata);`

Comment: yes it is giving me one record/array